# Java File mkdir gives false result

Tags: java, windows, file

So I'm trying to make a map to store some files in a `dir` that is made at the beginning of the program. But on windows there is still a problem, because the directory is never made. And I can't find a solution. The same code works perfect on a Unix system but not on a Windows system.

```
protected String createScreenshotMap(){
        this.dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        this.date = new Date();
        String testMap = this.checkOS();
        File fileMap = null;
        boolean check;
        try{
            if(os.indexOf("win") >= 0){
                fileMap = new File(testMap);
                check = fileMap.canWrite();
                System.out.println(check);
                String path = "C:" + File.separator + "testRun" + 
                                     File.separator + this.date.toString();
                fileMap = new File(path);
                System.out.println(fileMap.getAbsolutePath());
            }else{
                fileMap = new File(testMap + this.date.toString() + "/");
            }
            check = fileMap.mkdir();
            System.out.println(check);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return testMap;
    }
```

If I run this piece of code I get the following output

```
true
C:\testRun\Fri Apr 01 15:30:47 CEST 2016
false
```

I also checked I `testRun` exist and that was OK for java. i also checked if I could write and that gave true back, but it will still not make a `dir` in `testRun`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not create a folder or file name with `:` (colon)

**Details:**
Regarding Microsoft resources, the following characters are reserved by Windows and can not be used to creating folder or filename:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

Reference:

- [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)